# Can Windows 8 boot from FireWire?

Tags: boot, windows-8, firewire

I read many times Windows 7 is unable to boot from an external FireWire drive but I wonder if Windows 8 is able to do so.

I need to run Windows on my Mac but only very few times so my idea was to move it all to an external drive. I have one of the first Intel Macs so running Windows in a virtual machine is not really fun. The performance is just too poor.

Adding a Boot Camp partition to my internal drive is also not possible at the moment.

Comment: As long as the BIOS supports, yes it can..

Comment: @tumchaaditya: If Windows 7 can't, then why would Windows 8 be able to? Do you have an official source that confirms this support has been added to Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

If you use the regular Windows 8 setup, you will see the following message:

> Windows cannot be installed to this disk. Setup does not support configuration of or installation to disks connected through a USB or IEEE 1394 port.

But, if you have a Windows 7/8 BootCamp partition, you can use it to install Windows 8 on the external drive: [Is there an equivalent to Windows To Go for personal use?](https://superuser.com/questions/490362/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-to-go-for-personal-use)