# Upgrading to Windows 8 Enterprise edition

Tags: windows, upgrade, windows-8

Just came across [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/enterprise/products-and-technologies/windows-8/enterprise-edition.aspx) page for Windows 8 Enterprise Edition

I am particularly keen on Direct access without VPN as well as Windows to go. Can I upgrade to Enterprise directly from Windows 7 Pro or do I need to upgrade to Windows 8 Pro first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Upgrade to Windows Enterprise (Volume License)**
>
> You can upgrade to Windows 8 Enterprise (Volume License) from the following operating system editions:
>
> - Windows 7 Professional (Volume License)
> - Windows 7 Enterprise (Volume License)
> - Windows 8 (Volume License)

— **Source:** [TechNet - Windows 8 Upgrade Paths](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj203353.aspx)

So yes, upgrading is possible under volume license.

Comment: It's worth noting however that Windows 8 Enterprise is _only_ available through volume licensing, not for individual purchase. If VL isn't an option for you, check out [equivalent to Windows To Go for personal use](http://superuser.com/questions/490362/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-to-go-for-personal-use)

Comment: @nhinkle Technically Enterprise is not only available through VL - you can legally get Enterprise through MSDN/technet. Although those licenses are kind of fuzzy - I think the point is that you can only use it for your own personal use.