# Dual-boot Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

I currently have Windows 7 Home Premium, and I'm thinking about upgrading to Windows 8. Is it possible to use the Upgrade to dual-boot the two versions, or will the upgrade have to overwrite Windows 7? If it overwrites, is the process reversible to get Windows 7 back if I decide I don't like 8?

Comment: If you mean you upgrade for $40 from windows 7 then your license is **converted** to a windows 8 license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Do the following:

1. Run the Upgrade Assistant and buy the product key.
2. When it asks you to install, select `Install by creating media`.
   [image: S2]
3. Create the Windows 8 installer by using a USB flash drive or a DVD.
4. Boot the flash drive/DVD which contains the Windows 8 installer.
5. When it asks you to upgrade or do a clean install, choose `Custom`.
6. Create a new partition and install Windows 8 in it.

Now you can enjoy both Windows 7 and 8. If you don't like Windows 8, you can just delete the new partition that you created.

Also, you need to create a new partition on the internal drive. You can't install Windows 8 on an external drive that is connected through USB. The setup just doesn't support that. But there are [other ways](https://superuser.com/questions/490362/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-to-go-for-personal-use) by which you can install it on an external drive.

Comment: I didn't quite follow that - does the new partition go on the computer's hard drive? Could I use an external HD for it? Could you please elaborate a little on the steps to take?

Comment: You can do both. You can specify external or a new partition on the existing hard disk.

Comment: Since Windows 7 is not overwritten in this case, how will Windows 8 get activated?