# Using enclosed ssd as portable computer?

Tags: boot, ssd, external-hard-drive, portable, usb-3

I have a laptop with USB 3.0 ports and I have a solid state drive I never got around to installing on my desktop or using at all. I was thinking about buying an enclosure for it and booting off it on whichever computer I need to use. Is there any way to make this possible? I remember, when moving my hard drive over to my current desktop from my previous one, running into issues booting Windows.

So, two main questions:

**1. Would I run into any problems trying to boot off an external SSD connected by USB 3.0 to a laptop?**

**2. Is there a way I can install Windows or any other operating system and have the installation work across different hardware configurations?** (that is, install the OS while the drive is connected to my laptop, but then still be able to boot off it on my desktop)

Answer (score 1):

Windows dosen't generally handle different hardware combinations well - windows to go is an exception, and while its only officially supported on windows 8 enterprise edition, there's a [workaround for other versions](https://superuser.com/questions/490362/is-there-an-equivalent-to-windows-to-go-for-personal-use). Generally linux handles switching hardware well.

If you want to go with a USB enclosure, I'd go with USB 3.0 - its significantly faster, but the USB bus is still going to be a bottleneck for the drive.

Another option might be esata, its as fast as sata, boots, but its not very common.

Comment: If 'external SSD' also has SATA interface (besides USB), will Windows To Go boot when drive is connected internally using SATA.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to install OS, just enable boot from USB in bios. You may have some problems.

1.USB is slower than SATA

2.You will have some problems with the drivers, unless you want to reinstall drivers every time you switch between laptop and desktop.

3.If you want to use it as OS just stick with 1 pc.

4.If you really want to use different OS:s on same pc use some emulation programs like VMWare it would be much easier.

Comment: Ohh, VMware would actually be a really good idea. What if I carried around a portable version of VMWare?

Comment: Give it a try, i think i will work fine. So there you can install different OS with own drivers for each PC.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make an external hard drive your system drive, whether or not you boot from it, providing the BIOS supports that.  But the problem that you're up against is that each computer is likely to require different drivers.  i.e. would you really want to use generic VGA drivers for all those systems, instead of the graphics driver for the card that's in the system?

I'm curious as to what benefit you believe you might gain from this, as I can't see what would be worth compromising all your computer setups to a generic one-size-fits-all.

But yeah, it's possible to do it.  You could even just add the Windows install to the boot.ini file that's on the C: drive by default in XP, so that it knows there's a Windows install on this other device.  The procedure is a bit different for Win7, but again you can boot from C: and still have a valid selectable Windows install to start on another drive.

Also, the one critical spot where "one size fits all" is likely to fail is if the various computers have a mix of Intel & AMD CPUs;  Windows is very finicky about the CPU, and it's not easy to revert from one to the other.  The worst you get from a mix of audio hardware is that it won't work, and the worst from a mix of graphics drivers is that it will likely fall back on generic VGA ... but if the CPU mfr is not consistent, you'll get a Windows that won't boot at all.